VirtualProtect with PAGE_READONLY not working on variable
I am trying to set a variable to read only with VirtualProtect, however VirtualProtect returns 0 and GetLastError() gives 487 which is attempt to access invalid address. changing myVar = 77 confirms that VirtualProtect errors out.
int myVar = 42;
LPVOID address = &myVar;

SYSTEM_INFO si;
GetSystemInfo(&si);
SIZE_T pageSize = si.dwPageSize;

DWORD oldprotect;
int result = VirtualProtect(address,pageSize,PAGE_READONLY, &oldprotect);

cout << GetLastError() << " " << result << endl;
myVar = 77;
cout << myVar << endl;


I would recommend that you dynamically allocate a single page, and overlay a structure on it. Then protect that specific page, and all the member variables of the structure object will be protected.

Local variables exist on the call stack or in CPU registers (in this case, a register is not used since you are taking the address of the variable). You can't make either one read-only.
If you dynamically allocate the variable instead, you should then be able to make it read-only (just note that the entire memory page will be read-only, and likely will hold more data than just your variable).
int *myVar = new int(42);

DWORD oldprotect;
int result = VirtualProtect(myVar, sizeof(*myVar), PAGE_READONLY, &oldprotect);

cout << GetLastError() << " " << result << endl;

*myVar = 77;
cout << *myVar << endl;

VirtualProtect(myVar, sizeof(*myVar), oldprotect, &oldprotect);
delete myVar;


Using simple new may be problematic as new doesn't [normally] return a page aligned address. new doesn't know that VirtualProtect is being used here.  So, any subsequent ordinary new between the VirtualProtect calls will get get banjaxed. Under linux, I'd use mmap and mprotect. So, AFAICT [I'm not too familiar with the win32 API], we'd want to use VirtualAlloc (which returns a page aligned address) to get a buffer address. Then, use placement new. From a cursory look at the doc for VirtualProtect, it references the use of memory from VirtualAlloc.

@CraigEstey see Does VirtualProtect require the address of the beginning of the page? The thing to watch out for is the memory manager used underneath new may (likely) share a page for multiple/different allocations, and VirtualProtect can protect only whole pages. So you shouldn't protect a page you didn't allocate yourself.
